# Grouping stored procedure's result

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, telerik, radgrid

Hi I have the next store procedure

> `USE [BD_SSEGUA]
>   GO
>   /***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spAgendaDeSolicitudes]    Script Date: 10/14/2011 16:43:00 *****/
>   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
>   GO
>   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
>   GO
>   -- =============================================
>   -- Author:      Roque Ramírez Nájera
>   -- Create date: 23/03/2011
>   -- Description: Genera tabla de solicitudes
>   -- por estatus y año
>   -- spAgendaDeSolicitudes '2010'
>   -- =============================================

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAgendaDeSolicitudes]

@anio  varchar(5)
AS
     DECLARE

     @ContR     int,
     @ContRA        int,
     @ContRZ        int,
     @ContB     int,
      @ContC        int,
     @total     int

    DECLARE

     @agenda table ( periodo datetime, R int, A int, RZ int, B int, C int, TOTAL int)


      BEGIN



SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @ContR = COUNT (fiIdSolicitud) FROM Solicitud WHERE fiEdoSolicitud = 1 and fiAnioSolicitud = @anio
SELECT @ContRA = COUNT (fiIdSolicitud) FROM Solicitud WHERE fiEdoSolicitud = 2 and fiAnioSolicitud = @anio
SELECT @ContRZ = COUNT (fiIdSolicitud) FROM Solicitud WHERE fiEdoSolicitud = 3 and fiAnioSolicitud = @anio
SELECT @ContB = COUNT (fiIdSolicitud) FROM Solicitud WHERE fiEdoSolicitud = 4 and fiAnioSolicitud = @anio
SELECT @ContC = COUNT (fiIdSolicitud) FROM Solicitud WHERE fiEdoSolicitud = 5 and fiAnioSolicitud = @anio

SET @total = @ContR + @ContRA + @ContRZ + @ContB + @ContC

INSERT INTO @agenda  (R, A, RZ, B, C, TOTAL)
VALUES(@ContR,@ContRA,@ContRZ,@ContB,@ContC,@total)

SELECT R, A, RZ, B, C, TOTAL FROM @agenda END
```

`

I use this sp to fill a telerik radgrid the stored procedure gets as a result the count of requests per year sorted by status, this result is populated in a telerik radgrid.
R is for Registered
A is for Authorized
RZ is for Rejected and so on.

What I want to do is to group the results per year,month,week from the current year.
But the only field that I have is a datetime that corresponds the registration date which is in another table.

How can I solve this? 
Hope your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to group your data, you can create a CTE to add year/month/week corresponding to the datetime field and make your aggregate function in the CTE

here an example where I suppose that your temp table @agenda contains all the necessary data:

```
;WITH myCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        periodo, 
        YEAR(periodo) AS yearPart,
        MONTH(periodo) AS monthPart,
        DATEPART(WEEK, periodo) AS weekPart,
        R, A, RZ, B, C, 
        TOTAL int
    FROM @agenda
)
SELECT 
    yearPart, monthPart, weekPart, 
    SUM(R) AS R, SUM(A) AS A, SUM(RZ) as RZ, SUM(B) AS B, SUM(C) AS C, 
    SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
FROM myCTE
GROUP BY yearPart, monthPart, weekPart
```

Hope this helps :)